# how to insert rows that contain alteast one NaN values to another new Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is my sample dataframe

```
Code        Sales         Id
 AA         1000          23
 BB         NaN           43
 CC         3020          NaN
```

How can I append the rows that contains atleast one NaN value to new pandas Df

New DataFrame:

```
Code      Sales        Id
 BB        NaN         43
 CC        3020        NaN
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```